# jquery scrollTo offsetTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm using [jquery ScrollTo](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-scrollto) wonderfully but want to use the "offset top" add-on, has anyone set it up? I'm unsure of how to properly use it

```
$('#aAbout').click(function about() {
   $.scrollTo('#dAbout', 500, offsetTop: 10px);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't valid JavaScript syntax. Perhaps you meant:

```
$('#aAbout').click(function() {
    $('#dAbout').scrollTo({
        duration: 500, 
        offsetTop: '10px'
    });
});
```

Comment: yeah your right...that's a simple error on my part, I'll keep messing about.